# perform query on database for array of words

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How can I perform a query on database for an array of words. I have a key value pair database for separate words.
I have key value pair as two columns in database
I can get key-value pair for single words.
How can I get for array of words like performing query for multiple words.
Here is how I do for single words:

```
String srce = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "suggest_text_1");  
String trans = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "suggest_text_2");
```

**srce-trens**
Key-value
Hello-halo

Comment: you'd call select value from table where key in ("foo", "bar", "foobar");

Comment: @ njzk2 -Can you make in brief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

create a class

```
class KeyValPair
{
String text1;
String text2;

KeyValPair(String s1, String s2)
{
text1 = s1;
text2 = s2;
}
}
```

Then create an arrayList of type "keyValPair"

`ArrayList<KeyValPair> al_KeyValPair = new ArrayList<KeyValPair>;`
Then,

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select ...", null);

if(cursor.getCount()==0){
    //empty
    return false;
}else{
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
    al_KeyValPair.add(new KeyValPair(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1)));
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}else{
return false;
}
}
```